# ios http post param not send IONIC 3

Tags: http, post, ionic3

i try both of ionic native http and angular http

my code

```
var link = 'https://mydomain.tech/param.php';
var myData = JSON.stringify({username: 555});
this.http.post(link, myData).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
}, error => {
    console.log("Oooops!");
});
```

ionic native is

```
this.http.post('https://mydomain.domain', 
{ 
  cardToken : token,
  amount, 500
}, 
{
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
})
.then(data => {
  console.log(data.data);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error.status);
});
```

both work on android but ios post value not send

any advice ?

Comment: anything in the console?

Comment: no error http post successful just my value not send

Comment: well i print var_dump($_POST) on my server android return array(1) so it array 1 should be my post value  but ios return array(0)